# Does the Mac version of Starcraft II come with any performance issues?

Tags: pc, starcraft-2, macos

I'm curious if the Mac version of Starcraft II will perform approximately as well as the PC version on Bootcamp or if there will be any stability/performance compromises.  Is SCII a native port on Mac or is it wrapped?  Also, are the tech support teams separate (ie can we expect simultaneous and synchronized updates and bugs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest issue that I am aware of for Mac Starcraft 2 is that 10.6.4 makes the game very unstable if you have an nVidia graphics card. It crashed just often enough for me to get annoyed by it, so I re-installed my OS and only updated to 10.6.3. Things are much better now (this is likely the same issue as Steam has on 10.6.4, and probably requires a patch by Apple to fix - I'm not positive on this, though).

I'm not sure of the technical details of Starcraft 2 on the Mac, but I think that it is a native client. All of Blizzard's games (at least dating back to Diablo, maybe earlier) are released on Windows and Mac, so most likely they have a good build process for building their games cross platform.

There is a [Mac Technical Support](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/119207/) forum for Mac-only issues. That forum has a [known issues list](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/145754783) for the Mac client, as well.

Comment: actually 10.6.4 makes the graphics card in mac unstable, which is the underlying problem.